# Tasklet counts in /proc/softirqs increase very rapidly on USB operation in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, intel, interrupt-handling

I have a legacy device with following configuration:

- Chipset Architecture : Intel NM10 express
- CPU : Atom D2250 Dual Core
- Volatile Memory : 1GB
- CPU core : 4
- USB Host controller driver :  `ehci-pci`

When I perform any USB operation I observe increasing tasklet count linearly and if USB operation continues for a long time(approx half an hour) then tasklet count crosses a million and this seems to be very strange to me.

I read about interrupt handling mechanism used by `ehci-pci` which is not latest(i.e. PCI pin-based) but still the tasklet counts are so high in numbers.

I use `/proc/softirqs` to read tasklet count.

Any lead on this?

```
root@panther1:~# cat /proc/interrupts 
               CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
     23:          0          0          0    1411443   IO-APIC  23-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1, uhci_hcd:usb2

root@panther1:~# cat /proc/softirqs 
                    CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
          HI:          7          3         13    1125529
       TIMER:    2352846    2325384    2533628    2675821
      NET_TX:          0          0          2       1703
      NET_RX:       1161       1193       2730      51184
       BLOCK:          0          0          0          0
    IRQ_POLL:          0          0          0          0
     TASKLET:        256        164         90    1162220
       SCHED:    1078965    1015261    1155661    1207484
     HRTIMER:          0          0          0          0
         RCU:    1370647    1367098    1485356    1503762
```

Comment: Exponential, not linear?  So the number doubles every minute or something?

Comment: It is linear but very drastically increasing.. changed in question as well..thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I don't find something unusual in the tasklet **calls number** increasing as the time passed in a linear manner.

Comment: You mean it is expected behavior, right?

Comment: Yes, it looks normal for me: the more you read from USB device which uses tasklets, the more tasklets calls you get.